# I cannot sign into the App store. Any time I attempt to I get the same error

Tags: mac, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id

[image: Error Message displayed]

I have tried literally everything I can think of to include deleting my login information for the app store and and reentering it entirely. Unfortunately I cannot seem to find a solution despite the multiple forums I have encountered. Does anyone have any idea as to how to fix this issue?

Comment: With the OS X Mojave release they are in overload. Just try tomorrow.

Comment: This was going on way prior to the Mojave release unfortunately.

Comment: Can you log in at https://appleid.apple.com/ ?

Comment: Yes indeed, I absolutely can!

Comment: i've gone tothe Mac app store several times today with no issues. Maybe i was just lucky...

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to tell you, that is normal.

In times of new product release (OSX Mojave), they servers just get flooded with requests.

You are connected to App Store, but ca not pass the Log-In server.

It says, an `Unexpected Error` ?,

if anything is wrong with you profile or your log-in information it would tell you that.

The problem is not on your side !

Just have to keep trying.

[image: app store]

Answer (score 0):

first install AppCleaner application from related website. then,

Launch App Cleaner and then drag and drop the "App Store.app" onto the window. If it gives you an error prompt, just open the App Cleaner Preferences and uncheck the box next to "Protect default OS X apps" and then try it again.
Once successful, it will show all of the components associated with the App Store.app.
Select all of them EXCEPT for the App Store.app and the folder  /Library/Application Support.  For me, they were the first two in the list. Do Not delete those.

then reboot your computer and resign to App Store... and everything is ok mate...

Note: This is a citation from discussions.applestore.com site and tyvm for his/her helps to Checkyorself289